# Hierarchical clustering of weighted leaf nodes

Tags: scikit-learn, networkx, hierarchical-clustering

I have several samples related to each other according to a directed graph with one root (no inbound edges) and several leaf nodes (no outbound nodes).

I need to cluster the leaf nodes (samples) into `K` clusters, based on their weight (so that every cluster has approx the same total weight) and graph proximity (samples not directly adjacent in the graph cannot be in the same cluster).

For that I made a directional graph (networkx) and thought to use the `AgglomerativeClustering` algorithm from `scikit-learn` with connectivity, but I cannot get it to work.

I've tried to get the shortest distance between leaf nodes (to use as conectivity):

```
connectivity = [[nx.shortest_path_length(graph.to_undirected(), source=i, target=j, weight=None, method='dijkstra') for j in leaf_nodes] for i in leaf_nodes]
```

and cluster on the weights:

```
model = AgglomerativeClustering(linkage="ward", connectivity=connectivity, n_clusters=10).fit(leaf_nodes_weight)
```

But I am getting clusters across the graph.